# Radio button list selected item value issu

Tags: c#, asp.net, radiobuttonlist

i have a radio button list bound it with data by this method :

```
 DataTable dt1 = BeeStatus.GetAllBeeStatus();
 radio1.DataSource = dt1;
 radio1.DataTextField = "beeStatus";
 radio1.DataValueField = "beestatusID";
 radio1.DataBind();
```

when i am try to get the selected item value, by writing :

```
int st = Convert.ToInt32( radio1.SelectedItem.value);
```

it give this error :

[Server Error in '/' Application.

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current 
             web request. 
Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where 
     it originated in the code. ]
```

any help?

**Exception Details:** System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Some part of `radio1.SelectedItem.value` is null, inspect it in a debugger, e.g. if there is no value selected then radio1.SelectedItem will be null. You need to do a null check before trying to convert to an int.

Comment: i have check it, same error.

Answer (score 2):

Let me guess: you are databinding the `RadioButtonList` also on postback which prevents the event from being triggered. Check the `IsPostBack` property:

```
protected void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
         DataTable dt1 = BeeStatus.GetAllBeeStatus();
         radio1.DataSource = dt1;
         radio1.DataTextField = "beeStatus";
         radio1.DataValueField = "beestatusID";
         radio1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Otherwise `radio1.SelectedItem` is `null` because nothing is selected anymore.

Comment: no tim, the radio button is selected but there is no value.

Comment: @alim91: You get the exception at `radio1.SelectedItem.Value` because `radio1.SelectedItem` is `null` so you cannot access `item.Value`. One reason why it's not selected anymore is that you have called `radio1.DataBind();` before. That's why i have suggested to use the `IsPostBack`-property.